# How to get the return json success message after posting my json data in Window phone7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I am new to develop Windowsphone7 app,i have develop a small WP7 app in this i have post the json data,After posting success then it will return the Success message and one id .Now i want get the Success message and id .I dont know how can i get return data please anybody Help me to move from here please.  Here i post my code what i did to post json.

```
           private void SendOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double grossTotal = 0.0;
        List<MenuItem> mitems = new List<MenuItem>();

        foreach (var item in RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.Orders)
        {
            grossTotal += Convert.ToDouble(item.OrderTotal.TrimStart(new char[] { '$' }));

        }

        DateTime MyDateTime = ((DateTime)DateToDialIn.Value).Date.Add(((DateTime)TimeToDialIn.Value).TimeOfDay);
        ViewModel.RootObject root = new ViewModel.RootObject()
        {
            order = new ViewModel.Orders()
            {
                LocationId = Convert.ToInt32(RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.LocationPoco.LocationId),
                DeviceIdentifier = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")),
                OrderContactName = txtName.Text,
                OrderContactPhone = txtPhone.Text,
                OrderContactEmail = txtEmail.Text,
                ShipMethod = RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.ShipMethod,
                PickupDate = ((DateTime)DateToDialIn.Value).Date.Add(((DateTime)TimeToDialIn.Value).TimeOfDay).ToString(),
                Amount = grossTotal.ToString(),
                items = returnlist(mitems)
            },

        };

        string json = null;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ViewModel.RootObject));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, root);
            //stream.Flush();
            json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.mybusinessapp.com/restaurant/PlaceOrder"), "POST", json);
        string responce = client.ResponseHeaders.ToString();
       }

      void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

         RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.Orders = null;
        RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.ShipMethod = null;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu.xaml?LocationGUID=" + RestaurantApp.ViewModel.Generic.LocationPoco.LocationGuid, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a helper method like this:

```
    public static T JsonTo<T>(this string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T jsonObject;

        try
        {
            jsonObject = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException err)
        {
            ms.Close();
            return default(T);
        }
        ms.Close();
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Suppose your result json represents a YourResult instance:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.OpenReadCompleted += delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stream stream = e.Result;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            yourResult = reader.ReadToEnd().JsonTo<YourResult>();

        };

    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://your_api"));
```

Comment: Hi... thank you for giving replay, i solve my problem with out using helper method.i just get return message using e.Result.Thank you for Your replay...